# Neo4j on Mac: Prevent org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper from appearing in dock

Tags: java, macos, neo4j, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I installed neo4j with homebrew and everything works great. It is just annoying how when I start the server I get an icon in my dock titled `org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper`.

I had a similar icon with tomcat but I was able to easily remove it by adding `java.awt.headless=true` in to the catalina.properties config file. I tried adding the line to neo4j-server.properties and then neo4j.properties but I still got the icon.

**Mac Version:** Latest Mountain Lion (10.8.4 I think)

**Neo4j Version:** Community 1.9.2

Comment: With neo4j-community-2.0.0-M04 I do not have the bootstrapper showing up any more.

Comment: I will have to check the version. I installed via homebrew. Looks like homebrew version is `1.9.2`. I can check out 2.0.0-M04 but I would like to know how to get rid of the icon in my current version anyways. Or if someone knows a general fix for this inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the conf file and open `neo4j-wrapper.conf`

(you find it from `brew info neo4j`

look after `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.9-unix/libexec`

check `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.9-unix/libexec/conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`

open .)

And open up the neo4jwrapperfile

Before (Should be row 8 and 9)

```
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Add this:

```
wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.awt.headless=true to to conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf
```

Good luck!